# setting an array element with a sequence using np.zeros

Tags: python

I have two lists which are something like the below:

How can I put two of these lists in a list in the shape below:

```
final : [[],[]]
```

I did something like the below, but I encounter this error: "setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 1."

```
final = np.zeros((2,len(list))
final[0]=List_1
final[1]=List_2
```

List_1 & List_2:

```
[<mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe351327fd0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe375ea6b20>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe32b9d6670>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe40accf2b0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe41d8dcdc0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe339949cd0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe44c898d00>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe482d19fa0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe595827d00>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe6007bf3d0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe6412ca070>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe63cb92520>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe66d0c8eb0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5b1beff40>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe562563940>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe54fe6c280>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4cdbf5340>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4c92119a0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe47a43a850>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3a21059d0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3758bfc40>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe39f5a8040>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe30ac4c3d0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3065fb520>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3e1388160>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe617412e20>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5d2936dc0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe41c63cd90>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5016c5340>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe41c63cf70>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe654a44310>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe58b334f70>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4bad26cd0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe58b334c10>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5014c7fa0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe46d26a730>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe412f38850>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe451056b20>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5fc0a1d90>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe65b3a5190>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4fba2bc40>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe347811fa0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe61383c7f0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5ac38df40>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe53bf55c70>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5177a4a00>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5f7784790>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4c82d5bb0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4defc8d90>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe387f68220>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe430a85cd0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe387f68a30>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe387f689a0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4735886a0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe41c481d90>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe41c481160>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5037c74f0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3635f6430>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4fb692460>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe67040b160>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe66eb10f40>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3b5be0d60>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe6202ea400>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5037c7250>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe34279c760>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5782d2310>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe40ac57310>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3d343b5b0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe45d46a130>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe560e930d0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe36c043580>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe47076f610>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe47076fb20>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe594260370>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe6493aa3a0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe66d2e6910>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe443360d60>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe66d5b0790>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3ac3c17c0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe613bd5790>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe656332f70>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe62510bac0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe401b8d340>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5b5f330a0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe66e87e700>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4be025100>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe64dc51af0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe5bf186fd0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4be0252e0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe420cf8eb0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe420cf8220>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe46730bb80>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe44b5cb3d0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3e022daf0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3bedbb460>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe504162f70>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe4d0a90d60>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe3ad8594f0>,
 <mdtraj.Trajectory with 1 frames, 189 atoms, 189 residues, and unitcells at 0x7fe52960f310>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the two lists of same size?

If so, try this:

```
final = np.array([List_1, List_2])
```

This will give you a numpy array of shape = `(2, len(List_1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the array size in `numpy` directly, but a `list` can.

```
final = np.zeros((2,len(List_1))
final = list(final)
final[0]=List_1
final[1]=List_2
```